# Submitting a PHP form with multiple submit buttons

Tags: php, forms, submit

EDIT AGAIN: NEW REVISED VERSION

So I have corrected the lack of  tag in my table, I have added id's onto my forms, I have added a hidden field to each form with the same value as the form id also (as suggested)

I was trying to modify my original if isset to include form id's but thats where I have came a little unstuck.

As mentioned, here is the HTML that the page creates:

```
        <br><table border=1><tr><th>customer</th><th>product</th><th>employee</th><th>return_date</th><th>complete</th></tr><br><tr><td>marne1</td><td>basketball</td><td>user</td><td>01-10-12</td><td>        <FORM id="1" method ="post" action ="g.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='x' value='1'>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ir' value= '47'> 47        <input type="submit" name="return"/>
        </FORM>
        </td></tr><br><tr><td>marne1</td><td>basketball</td><td>user</td><td>01-10-12</td><td>      <FORM id="2" method ="post" action ="g.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='x' value='2'>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ir' value= '48'> 48        <input type="submit" name="return"/>
        </FORM>
        </td></tr><br><tr><td>marne1</td><td>basketball</td><td>user</td><td>02-10-12</td><td>      <FORM id="3" method ="post" action ="g.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='x' value='3'>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ir' value= '49'> 49        <input type="submit" name="return"/>
        </FORM>
        </td></tr><br><tr><td>marne1</td><td>basketball</td><td>user</td><td>29-09-12</td><td>      <FORM id="4" method ="post" action ="g.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='x' value='4'>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ir' value= '50'> 50        <input type="submit" name="return"/>
        </FORM>
        </td></tr><br><tr><td>marne1</td><td>basketball</td><td>user</td><td>01-10-12</td><td>      <FORM id="5" method ="post" action ="g.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='x' value='5'>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ir' value= '51'> 51        <input type="submit" name="return"/>
        </FORM>
        </td></tr><br><tr><td>marne1</td><td>basketball</td><td>user</td><td>01-10-12</td><td>      <FORM id="6" method ="post" action ="g.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='x' value='6'>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ir' value= '52'> 52        <input type="submit" name="return"/>
        </FORM>
        </td></tr><br><tr><td>marne1</td><td>basketball</td><td>user</td><td>02-10-12</td><td>      <FORM id="7" method ="post" action ="g.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='x' value='7'>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ir' value= '60'> 60        <input type="submit" name="return"/>
        </FORM>
        </td></tr><br><tr><td>marne1</td><td>basketball</td><td>user</td><td>02-10-12</td><td>      <FORM id="8" method ="post" action ="g.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='x' value='8'>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ir' value= '61'> 61        <input type="submit" name="return"/>
        </FORM>
        </td></tr><br></table> 

    <fieldset>
<legend>???</legend>
<form action="z.php" method="post">
Customer Name: <input type="text" name="ir" /> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="return"/>
</form>
```

This is the PHP page that is creating this HTML (with my porly attempted form id test):

```
    <?php
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_username = "root";  
$db_pass = "usbw";  
$db_name = "test"; 
mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rental WHERE customer = '$_POST[customer]' AND complete = '0' ") or die (mysql_error());
?> 

    <?php
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<table border=1>';
    echo '<tr><th>customer</th><th>product</th><th>employee</th><th>return_date</th><th>complete</th></tr>';
    echo "<br>";
    $x=1;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $row ['customer'];
        echo '</td><td>' ;
        echo $row ['product'];
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row ['employee'];
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row ['return_date'];
        echo '</td><td>';
        $cur_return = $row ['rental_id'];
        ?>
        <FORM id="<?php echo $x; ?>" method ="post" action ="g.php">
        <input type='hidden' name='x' value='<?php echo $x; ?>'>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ir' value= '<?php echo $cur_return ?>'> <?php echo $cur_return ?>
        <input type="submit" name="return"/>
        </FORM>
        <?php
    echo '</td></tr>'; 
    echo '<br>';
    $x++;
    }
    echo '</table>';
    ?> 

    <fieldset>
<legend>???</legend>
<form action="z.php" method="post">
Customer Name: <input type="text" name="ir" /> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="return"/>
</form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['return']))
    {
    if ($_POST['x']==1)
        {
        mysql_query("UPDATE rental SET complete = '1' WHERE rental_id = '$_POST[ir]'") or die (mysql_error());
        }   
    }
    ?>
```

I really do appreciate all the help you guys are suggesting, and apologies for the time it's taken me to get this sorted :)

Rich

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a question.

Comment: is that for your homework? ;-)

Comment: Sorry, my question was that it doesn't work... which is more of a statement, so I was wondering why it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait wait. You have multiple rows of data here and you want to submit one specific row of data, but have it all in the same form? I'm a little confused. It looks like what you're really looking for here is to generate a different form element for each row. But you cannot have multiple submit buttons submit different parts of the same form, that's not how forms work. A submit button will submit all data belonging to the form.

In that case, just move the opening form tag to the very beginning of the inside of your while loop, and move your submit button and closing form tag into the bottom of your while loop. It will generate each form and still maintain the structure of your table. But you cant have one form that submits only certain parts of itself, that goes against basic HTML principles.

I'd **strongly** suggest slapping an ID on each form, for future reference and update purposes.

Good luck.

Comment: I have amended my original code with your suggestions, but yet still having problems

Comment: Yeah, without you telling us more about what it's supposed to actually DO vs what it's currently DOING it's going to be hard for us to help you further. The form looks like it should be submitting correctly. What I suggest is posting just the HTML source so we can see and be sure that it's being generated properly (how you handle the data is PHP, but it sounds like you're having issues with the creation of the HTML code itself). We can tell you what it SHOULD look like, and from there we can talk about the PHP part if you still can't get it.

Comment: Also, when posting code (particularly PHP that generates HTML)-- clean it up more so we can read it easier. It's tough to see what's up. I revised it one more time and it looks like your opening table row (tr tag) for each row is not present- you have one opening tr tag BEFORE the while loop, which is probably helping to mess up your formatting (if that's an issue). You are also not IDing the forms still!

Comment: Hi dudewad, I have taken on all what you have said, forms are ID'd the TR tag has been placed in and I am attempting to trigger individual forms with the form id. I have posted both the PHP and the HTML above. Thanks again

Rich

Comment: Okay partway there. The HTML generates well in my browser. What are you trying to do now? You deleted the original question so I have no idea what the goal/problem is now :/
*edit* for the record- you  are putting br tags between each table row, which is not only unnecessary, I believe it would stack up to as much as "invalid markup". Tr and other table tags by nature create their own structure, that's the whole point. You don't need to add structural markup to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with javascript, but not with php.  But it's overcomplicating for no reason. Make different forms and assign them to different IDs.  You can use the same method="post" and the same action="g.php".  To differ on g.php, just put this in each form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='x' value='1'>
```

and then

```
<input type='hidden' name='x' value='2'>
```

Then it's a simple if $_POST['x']==1

Also, make sure you protect g.php, that's a pretty insecure name for a file that's handling forms.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Jeff, but I think my limited knowledge is making it hard to figure out how your solution would actually help me (plus I know almost no Javascript)

Comment: well you need to use a normal value.  Put $x=0 before the while loop.  Then at the BOTTOM of the loop $x++;

And then you do hidden input with a value of $x.

    <input type='hidden' name='x' value='$x'>.  

Echo that all out of course.  Same with the form id.

    <form id='$x' act.......>

Comment: Then you just need to expand your if($_POST['return']) statement to include the hidden values to differentiate the forms.